# Ubuntu 12.04 - Swiching Multiple Windows from a Program

Tags: 12.04

I'm having problem switching multiple windows from a same program.

For example, if I have 2 windows opened for Firefox at the same time and I wanted to switch from one another, it used to display a 2 small grid preview for each session when I click on the icon. However, that function doesn't seem to be working on my ubuntu 12.04 now. It doesn't response when I click on the Firefox (or other application) icon in the sidebar. Does anyone know how to fix this?

By the way, I know <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> can switch windows too, but it's hard to switch if I have 7 pdf documents opened at the same time. So I really wish to have this feature fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between windows of the same type. Instead of <kbd>tab</kbd> use the button directly above it, which can be different between keyboard layouts. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ButtonAboveTab</kbd> does the same thing that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> does, except directly between windows of that application.

Also, using <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>number of item</kbd> will bring up the switcher. For instance, if Nautilus is directly below the Ubuntu button and you have more than Nautilus window open, press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to focus Nautilus and than again to view all windows.

Comment: What is the "super" key?

Comment: It's the key with the logo on it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for a penguin sticker with a superman logo on it, to put on the key. :-)